# How to enable 'Web' logs in Yii 2?

Tags: php, logging, yii2

In Yii 1.x you have the CWebLogRoute class to log all your queries and stuff in your browser. Is this option already available for Yii 2.0? I only see the FileTarget, DbTarget and EmailTarget classes in the framework.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It's called debugger now in Yii 2.0. To enable it, put this in your configuration:

```
'preload' => ['debug'],
'modules' => [
    'debug' => 'yii\debug\Module'
],
```

Comment: param 'Preload' not exists

Comment: preload was replaced by bootstrap

Answer (score 9):

The correct answer:

```
return [
    'bootstrap' => ['debug'],
    'modules' => [
        'debug' => 'yii\debug\Module',
        // ...
    ],
];
```